# How do I make a kick, ban and clear command in this code?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I need to know how to I put in some moderation commands such as !ban, !kick and !clear. And i will give you the code i need instruction of where to put it at because i am new to coding and so if possible can you give me:

- Instruction on how to put the code in the code I have now
- Instruction on how to configure the code
- Instruction on where to put it
- Instruction on what command should I use to test the command

FYI: I am coding a discord bot with node.js. I have been doing research on the for a week please help me!!!

```
require('dotenv').config();
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

const TOKEN = process.env.TOKEN;

bot.login('TOKEN');

bot.on('ready', () => {
  console.info(`Logged in as ${bot.user.tag}!`);
});

bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === '!ping') {
        message.channel.send('Pong.');
    }
});

bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === '!getpizza') {
        message.channel.send('Welcome to Lynks Pizza!!! Heres your pizza and have a nice day!!!');
    }
});

bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === '!shutup') {
        message.channel.send('Okay, I am sorry.');
    }
});

bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === '!playdead') {
        message.channel.send(':dizzy_face:');
    }
});

bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === '!user-info') {
        message.channel.send(`Your username: ${message.author.username}\nYour ID: ${message.author.id}`);
    }
});

bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === '!server-info') {
        message.channel.send(`Server name: ${message.guild.name}\nTotal members: ${message.guild.memberCount}`);
    }
});
```

Comment: You should try using command handlers. If I recall correctly you should rarely use the same event handlers more than once. Check out this [guide](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/), it provides a good idea for making command handlers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put your whole code in only one file (and not on command handler), you can do

```
require('dotenv').config();
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

const TOKEN = process.env.TOKEN;

bot.login('TOKEN');

bot.on('ready', () => {
  console.info(`Logged in as ${bot.user.tag}!`);
});

bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === '!ping') {
        message.channel.send('Pong.');

    if (message.content === '!getpizza') {
        message.channel.send('Welcome to Lynks Pizza!!! Heres your pizza and have a nice day!!!');
    }


    if (message.content === '!shutup') {
        message.channel.send('Okay, I am sorry.');
    }


    if (message.content === '!playdead') {
        message.channel.send(':dizzy_face:');
    }



    if (message.content === '!user-info') {
        message.channel.send(`Your username: ${message.author.username}\nYour ID: ${message.author.id}`);
    }



    if (message.content === '!server-info') {
        message.channel.send(`Server name: ${message.guild.name}\nTotal members: ${message.guild.memberCount}`);
    }
});
```

The kick and the ban can looks like

```
if (message.content.startsWith("!kick ")) {
    if (message.mentions.members.first()) {
        message.mentions.members.first.kick().then((member) => {
            message.channel.send( member.displayName + " has been successfully kicked.");
        }).catch(() => {
            message.channel.send("I do not have permissions to do this");
        });
    }

 if (message.content.startsWith("!ban ")) {
   if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return;
    if (message.mentions.members.first()) {
        message.mentions.members.first.ban().then((member) => {
            message.channel.send(member.displayName + " has been successfully banned.");
        }).catch(() => {
            message.channel.send("I do not have permissions to do this");
        });
    }
}
```

So you can add this to your code:

```
bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith("!kick ")) {
        if (message.mentions.members.first()) {
            message.mentions.members.first.kick().then((member) => {
                message.channel.send( member.displayName + " has been successfully kicked.");
            }).catch(() => {
                message.channel.send("I do not have permissions to do this");
            });
        }
});

bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith("!ban ")) {
      if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return;
       if (message.mentions.members.first()) {
           message.mentions.members.first.ban().then((member) => {
               message.channel.send(member.displayName + " has been successfully banned.");
           }).catch(() => {
               message.channel.send("I do not have permissions to do this");
        });
    }
}
});
```